# Draw a simple decision tree

Tags: tikz-trees

I found this code but I just want to draw a very simple decision tree. I have tried to modify the code but I cannot get rid of the other branches. I only want S and then the two options "up" and "down".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
        grow                    = right,
        sibling distance        = 6em,
        level distance          = 10em,
        edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
        every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
        sloped
      ]
      \node [root] {S}
        child { node [env] {down}
          edge from parent node [below] {$40$} }
          child { node [env] {up}
          edge from parent node [below] {$20$} }
        child { node [dummy] {}
          child { node [dummy] {}
            child { node [env] {align\\flalign}
              edge from parent node [below] {at relation sign?} }
            child { node [env] {alignat}
              edge from parent node [above] {at several}
                               node [below] {places?} }
            child { node [env] {gather}
                    edge from parent node [above] {centered?} }
            edge from parent node [below] {aligned?} }
          child { node [env] {multline}
                  edge from parent node [above, align=center]
                    {first left,\\centered,}
                  node [below] {last right}}
                  edge from parent node [above] {$40$} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It would be much appreciated if someone could explain how this works since I am very new to LaTeX. Thanks a lot!

Comment: were you able to compile the above code

Comment: Yes, but I cannot delete the other branches.

Comment: Shoved code is not complete. Missed are package `tikz`, than definitions for your node styles (`root`, `dummy` and `env`). Please complete your document example to compilable document.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most relevant information about drawing trees by `tikz` package you will find in the package documentation (which is part of your `tikz` installation, or you can find it on CTAN: [Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en). In the section *21 Making Trees Grow*, page 333 -- 342 are described basics and in part *76 Tree Library*  are described use of `trees` library (which defines two new growth functions).

Anyway, in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below are codes for tree examples of very simply trees. The first two are drawn by pure `tikz`, the last one use `forest`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% common styles of tikz pictures elements
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center, 
                     minimum height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large\rmfamily, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
}

    \begin{document}
Using `tikz` tree growing right:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[% local settings for tree
grow                     = right,
sibling distance         = 6em,
level distance           = 10em,
edge from parent/.style  = {draw, -latex},
every node/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
                      ]
\node [root] {S}    % root node, here tree start, after it are childrens
    child { node [env] {down}
        edge from parent node [above] {Yes}}
    child { node [env] {up}
        edge from parent node [above] {No}} 
;
    \end{tikzpicture}

Using `tikz` tree growing down (default direction):

    \begin{tikzpicture}[% local settings for tree
%grow                     = right,
sibling distance         = 6em,
level distance           = 10em,
edge from parent/.style  = {draw, -latex},
every node/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped
                      ]
\node [root] {S}    % root node, here tree start, after it are childrens
    child { node [env] {down}
        edge from parent node [above] {Yes}}
    child { node [env] {up}
        edge from parent node [above] {No}}
;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
Using `forest` growing down:   

    \begin{forest}
for tree = {% settings for elemts in tree
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    font = \ttfamily,
    minimum height=2ex, text depth = 0.25ex,
   anchor = north, 
% edges 
     edge = {-Stealth},
    s sep = 3em,
    l sep = 6em
            },
EL/.style = {% shortenes for Edge Label, defined as style
   before typesetting nodes={% edge labels positioning
where n=1{edge label/.wrap value={node[pos=0.5,anchor=east]{#1}}}% above left
         {edge label/.wrap value={node[pos=0.5,anchor=west]{#1}}}% above right
                            }
            }% end of EL
% tree body
[ S, root % rot is style defined in document preamble
    [down, EL=Yes]
    [up, EL=No]
]
    \end{forest}
    \end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Beside this possibilities exist others too as `qtree` package ( [tikz-qtree: better trees with TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree?lang=en)) etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanation! That was very helpful. I have one more question: how can I draw two decision trees next to each other? I need two decision tree of the first type (growing right) next to each other.

Comment: @Lagrange, the simplest is to draw two independent images and insert them in parallel in document. However, less general answer you can get if you ask new question with more details, what is your problem, how images are related/connected and what you try so far.